# Error when I try EnumProcessModules in windows 8 64bit

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to pick up the modules of the process, according to msdn is not possible to handle the modules TH32CS_SNAPMODULE function in 32bit applications , using the EnumProcessModules function I can not list the modules of the defined process and go into an infinite loop.

I just had success compiling my application for Windows 64bit.

here is my code error !

```
procedure getmodule(ProcessID: Cardinal);
var
  Modules: array of HMODULE;
  cbNeeded, i: Cardinal;
  ModuleInfo: TModuleInfo;
  ModuleName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  PHandle: THandle;
  ITEM: TListItem;
begin
  SetLength(Modules, 1024);
  PHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION + PROCESS_VM_READ, False, ProcessID);
  if (PHandle <> 0) then
  begin
    EnumProcessModules(PHandle, @Modules[0], 1024 * SizeOf(HMODULE), cbNeeded); //Getting the enumeration of modules
    SetLength(Modules, cbNeeded div SizeOf(HMODULE)); //Setting the number of modules
    for i := 0 to Length(Modules) - 1 do //Start the loop
    begin
      item := Form1.listView2.Items.Add;
      ITEM.Caption := IntToStr(i); // Testing
    end;
    CloseHandle(PHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The documentation for `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` explains how to get both 32- and 64-bit modules in a snapshot from your 64-bit process. Include both `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` and `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` in your call.

Comment: example i tryng to get the modules list whit function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot but have some process that fail, example explorer i dont know why , but if i compile my app 64bits it work.
yes my call have TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32 and TH32CS_SNAPMODULE but the handle of modules is 0 .

Comment: see  ContinueLoop := Module32First(ModuleSnap, ModuleEntry);
       while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do begin

Comment: @RobKennedy I doubt that you'll be able to enumerate 64 bit modules from the WOW64 emulator. In the other direction, it will be fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why this happens and how I can handle the modules...

Comment: Because when you run a 32 bit process under Win 64 you are running in an emulator. And the emulator does support the entire of Win32.  It's an emulator.  If you want to do certain things, for instance things that give 64 bit pointers, you typically need to do that in a 64 bit process, outside the emulator.

Comment: Indeed, @David. I'm assuming we're running as a 64-bit process. The question claims success compiling for Windows 64-bit, after all. Mrhelp, if your program is actually a 32-bit program, then you cannot `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` to fetch information about 64-bit processes. I suspect you're still ignoring return values and error conditions. MSDN tells you what happens: "If the specified process is a 64-bit process and the caller is a 32-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299)."

Comment: @RobKennedy you guys are right, I really do not know how I will do this with a 32bit application, there is another api that I can handle the modules?

thanks guys.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any way. Compile your program as 64 bits instead.

Comment: Don't do it from the emulator. It's that simple.

Comment: whit a dll i can do it?

Comment: Don't do it from the emulator. That is, do it from a 64 bit process.

Comment: @MrHelp, what Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @whosrdaddy xe why ? >.<

Comment: You will need a higher Delphi version to compile your code for 64 bit...

Comment: I already compiled for 64bit, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't enter an infinite loop; you enter a very long loop. When `EnumProcessModules` fails, it evidently sets `cbNeeded := 0`. That sets the length of you array to zero, too. You then enter a loop starting at 0 and ending at –1. Interpreted as a `Cardinal`, the value –1 is 4294967295. It takes a long (but non-infinite) time to count that high, especially when you're adding items to a list view along the way. You probably got tired of waiting for your program and killed it before it finished running the loop.

There are at least two changes you need to make in order to proceed with your program:

1. Declare `i` as an `Integer` so that calculating `Length(Modules) - 1` doesn't underflow.
2. Pay attention to the return values of all your API calls. Never ignore an API return value. MSDN says that `EnumProcessModules` returns zero when it fails. Check for that. If it returns zero, then call `GetLastError` to find out the reason.

   Also, don't assume that 1024 is big enough for your array; it's possible that `cbNeeded` will be set to a higher number. When that happens, you'll iterate over more array items than you actually received. (The extra values will be null handles.)